# How to set element on ion-header-bar becouse it covered element?

Tags: ionic-framework

I am trying put element under header but unfortunately it not working.
My element is directive and it I am using for  specific pages.
I am set it `position:absolute` and `z-index:500` and for `ion-header`  i am set `z-index:1` but it not working

Please help me[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYELh.jpg)

Comment: Consider reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and edit your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the correct answer. Here is it:

```
<ion-nav-buttons side="right"> //button here 
</ion-nav-buttons>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are expecting this one

```
<ion-content>
    <ion-fab edge right top>
      <button ion-fab>
        <ion-icon name="warning"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-fab>
</ion-content>
```

Refer this 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-gs9df1?file=pages%2Fhome%2Fhome.html

Comment: This example made by ionic 2.
Thanks a lot for answer,but I found the correct answer.
here is it

  <ion-nav-buttons side="right">

//button here
  </ion-nav-buttons>